# ASp.NET core : While making Post Request encoded data variable found null

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, api, post

Hello I'm making post request from the web app but encodedData variable is found null while debugging.

jsonData variable is having string of my model but after serializing encodedData variable is null.

**Below are the images**

[null encodedData object Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26QoI.png)

[jsonData with having value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F97gB.png)

```
string url = "http://localhost:44392/api/Auth/Login";
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
var encodedData = new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsync(url, encodedData).Result;
```

Comment: in you first screenshot `encodedData` variable value is not assigned yet

Answer (score 0):

I have executed same code in my sample application its working as expected means not a null value in encodedData variable. Just check value after assigned to value as mentioned by @Arsen

See the attached screenshot of my debugging session.

[image]